# Is it possible to write a root route with a file extension in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I'm writing a JSON API with Sinatra and I'm separating the different resources into `Sinatra::Base` classes using the `map` command:

```
map('/people') { run Api::People }
```

Within `Api::People`, `/people` would be mapped as the root path `/`. I'd like `/people.json` to be handled via `Api::People` -- is this possible? I can't figure out how to write the route.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/intridea/grape since it's build for APIs and you can hook it up next to your Sinatra app

Comment: @daddz might not be mature enough for us, but I'll try it out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a second mapping is required:

```
map('/people')      { run Api::People }
map('/people.json') { run Api::People }
```

When I add that, `/people.json` is sent to the root path of `Api::People` as I wanted.

---

The problem with this approach is that I have a lot of nested resources, with translates into a *lot* of repetitive mappings.

I've settled on a design that is both elegant and logically consistent. Did you know a `Sinatra::Base` class can mount other `Sinatra::Base` classes inside itself as middleware?

Once I figured that out, the solution is obvious:

**config.ru**

```
Dir['api/**/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }

run API::Router
```

**api/router.rb**

```
module API
  class Router < Sinatra::Base
    use Businesses
    use People
    use Users

    get '*' do
      not_found
    end
  end
end
```

**api/businesses.rb**

```
class API::Businesses < Sinatra::Base
  use Locations

  get '/businesses.json' do ... end
  get '/businesses/:id.json' do ... end
end
```

**api/businesses/locations.rb**

```
class API::Businesses < Sinatra::Base
  class Locations < Sinatra::Base
    before { @business = Business.find_by_id( params[:business_id] ) }
    get '/businesses/:business_id/locations.json' do ... end
    get '/businesses/:business_id/locations/:id.json' do ... end
  end
end
```

An additional benefit is that all routes are complete, so you don't have to constantly remember what '/' is actually mapping to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a DRYer alternative:

```
%w(people people.json).each do |route|
  map('/' + route) { run Api::People }
end
```

or you could include the slash in the array like `%w(/path/to/api /path/to/api.json)`